# how can I Mosaic/Merge four GeoTIFF land cover data sets using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff, merge

I have been trying to merge these land cover GeoTIFF files shown in the attached images using ArcGIS Pro, but every time I do so
the classes get turned into bands.
How can I merge them, while keeping the classes?

edit: ( I have used Mosaic To New Raster but with no success)

[image: data]

[image: classes]

[image: not what I wanted]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to indicate the tool and options you have tried.

Comment: You need to show how you are "merging" your rasters. In the world of rasters you typically mosaic rasters not merge.

Comment: yes I did try to mosaic them, I even created a mosaic dataset and that got around the display issue but still all the classes I have got turned into 3 bands image in the process and I want those classes to stay as they are

Comment: Its not enough to say which tool you have used. You need to include screenshots of the tool and how you are using it as well as screen shots of the layer properties, especial the data source so we can understand if you are using a 1-band or multi-band as input.

Comment: thank you for your willingness to help. I solved the issue by using the reclassification tool, I reclassed the rasters and then merged them using the merge tool in the raster function and that did the trick!